# Customizing the Content-Disposition when returning a file in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an endpoint that returns a file, but also includes the parameter "name=file" in the Content-Disposition. Working with the standard File method that returns FileContentResult doesn't work, as it overrides the Content-Disposition at some point.

I'm trying to create my own implementation of IActionResult that will let me specify the Content-Disposition, but after calling this endpoint and inspecting the Content of the HttpResponseMessage, the Content Headers doesn't have the Content-Disposition set at all.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile()
{
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(this.OpenFile(@"C:\Data.tar"));

    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file", 
            FileName = "data.tar",
            FileNameStar = "data.tar",
        };

    return new CustomFileResult(streamContent);
}



public class CustomFileResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpContent _content;

    public CustomFileResult(HttpContent content)
    {
        _content = content;
    }
    
    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = _content.Headers.ContentLength;
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = _content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        
        await _content.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);

        if(_content is StreamContent)
            _content.Dispose();
    }
}
```

These content headers are returned from the above code:

[image]

How can I modify this code so that the Content-Disposition is returned with the file data?

Comment: Your `CustomFileResult`'s `ExecuteResultAsync` doesn't forward the **Content-Disposition** header inside the `HttpContent` object.  You are explicitly forwarding to the response only the content length and the content type.  That's it.  Forward Content-Disposition too.

Comment: Oh man, that was it! Thank you so much. I think I got blind after trying to figure this out for to long. Thanks again